# Mistery: GetIntField() and ordinal () return different values

Tags: java, enums, java-native-interface

I have an enum class like this:

```
public enum EProjector {
            eOff (0),             
            eLow (1),             
            eHigh (2);          

    EProjector(int code)
    {
        this.mCode = code;
        System.out.println(" EProjector mcode " + mCode);
    }

    private static final Map<Integer, EProjector> typesByValue = new HashMap<Integer, EProjector>();

    static {
        for (EProjector type : EProjector.values()) {
            typesByValue.put(type.mCode, type);
        }
    }

    public static EProjector forValue(int value) {
        return  typesByValue.get(value);
    }

    private int mCode;
}
```

**When I am trying to use this enum in JNI, GetIntField returns 2 for eOff, while ordinal retuns 0, as it should be.**

For eLow and eHigh both return the correct values.

```
jobject JNICALL Java_MyPackage_MyClass_setProjector(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject iLevel)
{
    jclass level_class = (jclass) env->FindClass("MyPackage/EProjector");
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(level_class, "mCode", "I");
    int value1 = env->GetIntField(iLevel,fid);
    LOGE("EProjector from field  %d", value1 );

    jmethodID getValueMethod = env->GetMethodID(level_class, "ordinal", "()I");
    jint value2 = env->CallIntMethod(iLevel, getValueMethod);
    LOGE("EProjector from ordinal %d ", (int)value2);


      // ......
}
```

Why? What is wrong here?

Comment: What's your target environment? I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe on Android (I changed `FindClass` to `GetObjectClass` but I don't really see how that would affect anything).

Comment: Android 21, ndk10d, arm64-v8a. The code is exactly the same, as above, except for the package name, and it is always happening, the bug is very stable.